# why can't I see the file from carbon fields?

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem is the following, I use wordpress and make my own theme. I want to make a custom field using carbon fields, into which I can upload a file and after saving the record, this file should be placed in the folder I need, but when I started looking for errors and arranging logs, I found out the following: I fill in the fields and upload the file to my custom field, then click save and in the logs I see a message that the file did not have any data, I started checking and it turned out that he just did not see it, he could not download it from my field. Why is this happening?

```
add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields', 'crb_attach_post_meta');
function crb_attach_post_meta() {
    Container::make('post_meta', __('add a', 'crb'))
        ->where('post_type', '=', 'post')
        ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('text', 'crb_g_title', 'title '), 
            Field::make('text', 'crb_additional_seo_g', 'SEO'),
            Field::make('text', 'crb_additional_about_g', 'about'),
            Field::make('text', 'crb_additional_c', 'Con'),
            Field::make('file', 'crb_g_files', 'load file')
                ->set_required(true) 
                ->set_help_text('loadfile'),
        ));
}



add_action('save_post', 'crb_save_post', 10, 3);

function crb_save_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
   if (empty($_FILES['crb_g_files'])) {
        error_log(" i have file load error");
        return;
    }
}
```